# Count functions calls with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, closures, prototype

For example: I have a lot of functions and use them many times.
I need to count calls for each function.
What is the best practice to make it?

At first i thought i need closures, but I can't implement it in a right way.

Comment: on what end do you need the result? back/user?

Comment: Are the results a continuous count, session based, etc??

Comment: i need just vars with number of calls, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can decorate each function with a profiling wrapper:

```js
_calls = {}

profile = function(fn) {
    return function() {
        _calls[fn.name] = (_calls[fn.name] || 0) + 1;
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

function foo() {
    bar()
    bar()
}

function bar() {
}

foo = profile(foo)
bar = profile(bar)

foo()
foo()

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(_calls,0,3));
```

For serious debugging, you might be better off with a dedicated profiler (usually located in your browser's console).

Comment: i get `"undefined": 6` on ie11

Comment: Then go for: profile = function (fn, fnname) and specify the name of the function manually when calling it

Comment: Thank you for answer, it is very useful ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<script>
    var aCalls = 0;
    var bCalls = 0;
    function a()
    {
        aCalls = aCalls + 1;
        alert(aCalls);
    }
    function b()
    {
        bCalls = bCalls + 1;
        alert(bCalls);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fullfill the requirement of the question. Why are there two variables and you only keep them in variables, you don't display them.

Comment: He asked for a counting system for each function.

Comment: Oh yes. He asked for count only. Sorry, must've read it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

function myfunction()
{
    count++;
    alert( "Function called " + count);
}


myfunction();
myfunction();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xsdzpmwm/3/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a profiler.

On IE: press F12 to open developer tools, then go to the Profiler tab, and hit the play button. After stopping the profiler, you'll be presented with a lot of info (number of calls for each function, inclusive time, exclusive time, etc.)

On Chrome: press F12, go to Profiles, Collect JavaScript CPU Profile (that won't tell you the number of calls though)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would add a property “count” to the function itself.

Just add one line at the beginning of your function you want to have tracked calls.

```
function func() {
  func.count = (func.count || 0) + 1;
  // first time you call the function func.count is undefined so use 0 instead 
  console.log("hi");
}

func();
console.log(func.count) // 1
func();
func();
func();
console.log(func.count) // 4
```

Functions are objects in javascript after all. No pollution of global namespace, no wrapping or closures needed, very simple to understand and to write.